# How to access cells from programmatically created datagridview in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

When creating a datagridview in VB.net I cannot get at the cells from anywhere except the Sub where it was made.
I tried placing the code in Form_Load and tried make the Sub Public.
I use Controls.Find, which finds the datagridview, but I cannot access any rows or cells. I can create textbox and label controls and access their text content from anywhere, but not so with the datagridview. This is odd to me.
Using and learning Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2017, for use in my own home business utility.

```
Dim dgv As New DataGridView
dgv.Location = New Point(2, 200)
dgv.Size = New Size(300, 50)
dgv.Name = "NewDGV"
Dim ColumnTitles() As String = {"ProdId", "Price"}
Dim ColumnWidths() As Integer = {50, 50) 
For i = 0 To UBound(ColumnTitles)
    Dim col As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    col.DataPropertyName = ColumnTitles(i)
    col.HeaderText = ColumnTitles(i)
    col.Name = ColumnTitles(i)
    col.Width = ColumnWidths(i)
    dgv.Columns.Add(col)
Next
Controls.Add(dgv)
‘the following sees the datagridview just fine 
‘within the same sub   
Dim x = dgv.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value
```

This is how I am creating this control. Perhaps I am Adding to Controls in the wrong way? I am open to better ways to do this.

Comment: Move `Dim dgv As New DataGridView` outside the method and declare it as a Field: `Private dgv As DataGridView = Nothing`. In the method that defines it, use `dgv = New DataGridView()` to initialize it. You can access the `dgv` instance from anywhere in the class where it's declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = CType(Controls("NewDGV"), DataGridView)

    dgv.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value = "I found you!"
```

What this does is find the first Control in the Controls collection, coerces it into a DataGridView type, and assigns it to the variable dgv. You can than manipulate dgv. In this case I put some text in the first cell on the first row.

Comment: much better plan than linq.

Comment: I did as you said, declared the datagridview. Decided just to do that in Form1_Load for now. Then under a button event I put your suggested line and it did work. Finally, I can access the information in the grid. Thanks!
Any suggested reading on this solution?
Still working on the other answers...

Comment: @GAHiebert Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could ask the control collection for the instance of your datagridview

```
Dim MyDgv As DataGridView = Controls.Cast(Of DataGridView).First(Function(dgv) dgv.Name = "NewDGV")
```

Then work with "MyDGV" properties, methods, and/or events

Comment: Is that VB.net?